# android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item shows: 'Expected class or package'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: This keeps on showing even after making changes to my code changes.]

This keeps on showing even after making changes to my code changes. As I'm new to Android Development, I don't know much about fixing all these issues. Neither I've found any relevant information regarding this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    val artistas = listOf(
        "Romeo Santos", "Hot Chili", "Jaguares", "Caifanes", "Cafe tacuba",
        "Mana", "Farruko", "Don omar", "Los toros van", "Ozone", "Marylin Manson", "Audioslave", "Linkin Park")

    val adapter =
        ArrayAdapter(applicationContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, artistas)
    listView.adapter = adapter
```

If this doesn't work, usually restarting and invalidating cache will fix it